# Remove java 7 after java 8 installed?

Tags: java

So, I don't know if here is the right place for such as qustion, but:

Just now I installed java 8.

Is java 7 still relevant or I can remove it? Thanks!

Comment: Surely if it was an update it would have removed earlier versions before hand? or is it a separate install?

Comment: Yes it is installed; Java does no remove the previous version of Java when its installed. This means you can have Java 8 Update 10 and Java 8 Update 11 on your machine. This is the reason you can still be vulerable to Java exploits even if you have the current version installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless any of your installed programs specifically use version 7 of Java then there is no need for it to be still installed after version 8 is installed. I would check see if any of your programs use that version of Java and then if you are happy that none of them will be effected you can be confident that you do not need version 7 if you are running version 8

Comment: Thanks! and what about web apps? Java 8 is good for them?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain it would only be a matter of testing them

Comment: @Dave - Sure;  If Java 7 was good for web applications then Java 8 is good for them, not sure, how that has anything to do with your question though.

Comment: @Ramhound He might be trying to distinguish whether he needs Java 7 for all of his applications if Java 8 can support them or indeed which ones wont be supported if any.

Comment: @NathanTaylor - I suspect your giving the author way to much credit.

Comment: @Ramhound in what way?